# jQuery Cycle 2 not working when i pull it in externally

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

My site is using the jQuery cycle2 plugin.

My problem is im pulling in external HTML chunks into my site to create a 'one page website'. The plugin works fine until i pull it in externally then it stops working. (doesnt function and pagination disappears).

The previous version of cycle plugin works fine but id rather use cycle2 as its better responsively (my site is responsive).

This is my dev site - see the 'OUR NEWS' PAGE - this is where problem occurs
http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/chaos2013-2/

Thanks

i've tried pulling in the plugin with a .getScript within my ajax file with pulls all other JS into this page successfully but still nothing:

```
 $.getScript( "../js/jquery.cycle2.js" )
```

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Any code you can share?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading the jquery.cycle2.js plugin before loading the jquery.min.js file, and you are getting the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

You have `<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>` in your `head`,
but you have `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `footer`

Just add the jquery.cycle2.js plugin after all the rest in the footer, and try that.

Comment: I've changed the position but it still doesnt work, also my orignal jQuery Cycle on the home page has now stopped working too. Im pretty sure the issue is the fact the page is being pulled in after the initial load. With all other pages i pull the JS in aswell but with the new set up of cycle2 it doesnt have any JS other than the plugin so i cant for this :-/

Comment: It looks like you are still using the original cycle on the slideshowHome div.  According to the FAQ, you cannot use cycle and cycle2 on the same page.  Also, maybe try to reinitialize the OurNews cycle after your $.getScript() call with: $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('reinit');